# Variable Scope outside jQuery function with keyup change

Tags: jquery

I try to understand scope in jquery, in this function,i try to use my 2 vars in the third function (the one with console.log), it works well like this but i want change the first and the second function with :

```
$("#sizeclass").on("keyup change", function() {
    sizeclass = $(this).val();
});
```

my var returns nothing,

Thanks for reading me

```
var sizeclass = '';
var strippedclass = '';

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

    $(function(){
        strippedclass = 'strippedclass';
    });

    $(function() {
        sizeclass = 'sizeclass';
    }); 

    $(function(){
        console.log ('strippedclass outside=' + strippedclass) ;
        console.log ('sizeclass outside=' + sizeclass) ;   
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exnMQ/1/)

why use jQuery(document).ready(function(**$**) $ here it is conflict with other function
like:

```
$(function(){
           strippedclass = 'strippedclass';
           });
```

Comment: hi because i'm within the wordpress environment